# What should I do when an application developed by Codelab based on Health Kit reads activity data and errors?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

An application developed by Codelab based on Health Kit reports an error when reading activity records and displays the error message：
java.lang.SecurityException: 50005 and NullPointerException / Unknown error code 907135002。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The application may not be authorized to read and write activity data.
2. The HMS Core version may be too low.
   If your application reports an error when reading activity records, please check whether the application data permission is enabled. If the application still reports an error, it may be that you have not applied for the sports health data service or the application failed. Please proceed as follows:
   a)Click "Sports Health Service."
   b)Click "Apply for Health Kit Service", after agreeing to the agreement, enter the data permission application page.
   c)Check and submit the data permission that the product must apply for.
   d)Feedback application information.